# TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'. in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I got this error when running the code below that I found online regarding defining the machine learning model:

```
raise TypeError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name, e))
TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a
bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

customers = pd.read_csv('EcommerceCustomers.csv')

X = customers[['Avg. Session Length', 'Time on App', 'Time on Website','Length of Membership']].values
y = customers['Yearly Amount Spent'].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_training, X_testing, Y_training, Y_testing = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=101)

Y_training= np.reshape(Y_training, (-1, 1))
Y_testing= np.reshape(Y_testing, (-1, 1))

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
Y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

X_scaled_training = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_training)
Y_scaled_training = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y_training)

X_scaled_testing = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_testing)
Y_scaled_testing = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y_testing)

print(X_scaled_testing.shape)
print(Y_scaled_testing.shape)

print("Note: Y values were scaled by multiplying by {:.10f} and adding {:.4f}".format(Y_scaler.scale_[0], Y_scaler.min_[0]))

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")
```

The error occurrs at this line:

```
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=, activation='relu'))`
```

What is the reason for this kind of issue?  I tried many examples, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: This `Dense(50, input_dim=, activation='relu')` should give you an `invalid syntax` error.

Comment: @MarredCheese: Don't accept edits that break error message formatting.

Comment: (Not that it was correct in the first place, and the code was clearly never actually run in this form, but quote-formatting just makes it even worse.)

Comment: @user2357112 Ok, I put it back to how it was originally.

Comment: Is your problem fixed?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, this line has a typo:

```
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=, activation='relu'))
```

The parameter `input_dim` should be the shape (flattened) of the array that you are planning to feed to that layer. I actually recommend using `input_shape` instead.

Try this:

```
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=X[0].shape, activation='relu'))
```

Take a look at [keras reference docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#specifying-the-input-shape)

Comment: `,` isn't interpreted as a tuple. This code completely fails to parse.

Comment: You're right! I will try to correct the answer. I'm used to having valid code confused with tuples by typos, for example: `x = 1,` already happened to me more than once.

Answer (score 1):

This line will result in syntax error.
`Dense(50, input_dim=, activation='relu')`

```
In [1]: Dense(50, input_dim=, activation='relu')
  File "<ipython-input-2-ed8b4d6f4769>", line 1
    Dense(50, input_dim=, activation='relu')
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You cannot leave `input_dim` empty while calling `keras.layers.Dense` you have to pass either `input_dim`  or `input_shape`.

```
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=(16, ), activation='relu'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with tensorflow 2.0 and new keras, I used the `input_dim` parameters, but I should do `input_shape`:

```
model_1.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,50,3)))
```